# Displaying left join with multiple values that need to be accumulated

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have a table of 'URLs', and each of the 'URLs' may have multiple 'conversions' attached to them. I want to accumulate the numerical value of all the conversions ($), and count the amount of conversions related to each URL aswell.

At the moment I'm using a left outer join to join the url table to the conversion table, but this just repeats the URL record if there's multiple conversions attached. I want to know what I can do to solve this, be it on the database side or logic side (I'm using PHP/CodeIgniter.)

If it helps, here is the CodeIgniter Active Record Query:

```
    $this->db->select('url.id, url.url, url.clicks,url.affiliate_url,conversion.commission');
    $this->db->from('url');
    $this->db->join('conversion', 'url.id = conversion.url_id','left outer');
    $this->db->where('url.user_id = '.$this->user_id);
    $this->db->order_by('url.id','DESC');
    $data['urls'] = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Thanks in advance!

Tom

Solution:

```
$this->db->select('url.id, url.url, url.clicks,url.affiliate_url,count(conversion.id) AS conversions,sum(conversion.commission) AS earnings');
$this->db->from('url');
$this->db->join('conversion', 'url.id = conversion.url_id','left outer');
$this->db->where('url.user_id = '.$this->user_id);
$this->db->group_by('url.id'); 
$this->db->order_by('url.id','DESC');
$data['urls'] = $this->db->get()->result();
enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by the URL:

```
SELECT url.id, url.url, sum(url.clicks), count(url.clicks,url.affiliate_url), sum(conversion.commission)
FROM url
LEFT JOIN conversion ON url.id = conversion.url_id
WHERE url.user_id = ?
GROUP BY url.id, url.url
ORDER BY url.id DESC
```

Sorry it isn't in codeigniter, but I'm sure your able to convert.

Comment: You'll want to index the GROUP BY columns as well.

Comment: Good point Bruce, this will speed up your query nicely. Bear in mind it may slow your updates and inserts down a bit if the table is massive (millions of rows).

Answer (score 2):

this should do the trick.

```
$this->db->select('url.id, url.url, url.clicks,url.affiliate_url,conversion.commission');
$this->db->select_sum('conversion.commission');
$this->db->from('url');
$this->db->join('conversion', 'url.id = conversion.url_id','left outer');
$this->db->where('url.user_id = '.$this->user_id);
$this->db->group_by('url.id'); 
$this->db->order_by('url.id','DESC');
```

You need to group your results by url's id and sum up the conversions. good luck ;)

p.s. i haven't worked with ci, but these are the methods for what you need (lines 2 & 6)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I used a similar query (editted into the post above.)